# How can I change paragraph order using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

on this registration page http://energies2050.org/wp-login.php?action=register
i would like to change the order of the paragraphs to be:

Identifiant

Civilite :

First Name:

Last Name:

E-mail

Telephone:

About Yourself:

Motivation pour participer au Forum:

Sujets que vous aimeriez voir sur le Forum:

Password:

Confirm Password:

Disclaimer

Would that be doable in jQuery?

Comment: Why can't you just edit the HTML itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did

```
jQuery("#registerform > p").addClass("register");

var p = 0;
        jQuery('#registerform').find('p').each(function(){
                if(p<100){
                        p++;
                }
                else{
                        p = 1;
                }
                jQuery(this).addClass('p-' + p);
        });
jQuery("#registerform .p-9").insertBefore("#registerform .p-1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) part of JQuery API. You will find the functions you need in this context.